# Alternative to a span class in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

This is a really basic question about Wordpress functionality.

If I was making a static site and I wanted to apply special styles or code to a few words in my content I would use `<span class="">`. Is there some way to do this in Wordpress? More specifically I want to allow the user to add content in a custom field, but be able to tag a few words in that content as say class="movie-title".

That way I can style the class in a particular way without relying on the user to apply consistent styling.

Edit: Solved--- For anyone reading this I simply decided to create custom shortcodes which added span tags with a class around the the content. This only works in Advanced Custom Fields if you use a WYSIWYG field. I also added a button in the tinyMCE editor which automatically inserts the custom shortcode around a highlighted word when clicked.

Comment: There are several ways you can do this.  You could do it via a shortcode, add a "styles" dropdown to the tinymce editor or even a filter.  If the movie title matches the post title you could search the content before displaying and then apply your span and class there.  It really all depends on your current set up and how you are currently manipulating wordpress.  Perhaps you can elaborate on your scenario to determine the best possible solution.

Comment: Im pretty new to Wordpress so let me know if there is anything else specific that would help: Basically I have created a few Pages and have been using Custom Fields and the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to allow the user to add small and large bits of content. In this case, the user would be adding a larger amount of content to the page either via a wysiwyg advanced custom field or just a text area custom field. Within that paragraph I want to single out the movie title. I also need to be able to tag other parts of the content, like the director's name, with its own unique identifier

Comment: Have you created separate fields for movie title and directors name?  If so I think a filter would be the best way to go.  This would allow you to get the desired styling without the user having to do anything more than enter the data into the fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, I'll do some research into implementing filters in wordpress to get this done. Thanks for saving me hours of online research to figure out what direction to go with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is this: [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/). According to the description, it will:
"Imports the CSS classes from the theme stylesheet and add them to a drop-down list." I haven't used it myself, but from what I've heard it's quite flexible.

If you want to be able to use it in custom fields, you should also take a look at [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). It will allow you to add the TinyMCE editor to them.